# Converting python dictionary value into nested keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'expert_interests': "['Machine learning', 'deep learning']"}
```

As you can see the the value of the key "expert_interests" is the String "['Machine learning', 'deep learning']".

I want to convert this string value into a nested dictionary such that the dictionary looks like this:

```
{'expert_interests': [
      {
        "title": "Machine learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "deep learning"
        
      }
      
    ]
    }
```

I do not know how to approach this problem.Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). This function is like `eval`, except it will only evaluate literals, so it's safer from attacks.

From the documentation (linked above),

> There is no namespace, no name lookups, or ability to call out. But it is not free from attack: A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption denial of service on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended.

```py
import ast

data = {'expert_interests': "['Machine learning', 'deep learning']"}

data["expert_interests"] = [
  {"title": title}
  for title
  in ast.literal_eval(data["expert_interests"])
]

print(data)
# {'expert_interests': [{'title': 'Machine learning'}, {'title': 'deep learning'}]}
```

Another option is to use `json.loads` to convert it to a list of strings, then just make each a dictionary.

The only problems with this are that it blindly replaces `'` with `"` (since the JSON standard only uses `"` for strings) which can lead to errors if you have `"` or `\'` anywhere in your string, but this is better than `eval` because [`eval` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) especially when you can't trust the source.

```py
import json

data = {'expert_interests': "['Machine learning', 'deep learning']"}

data["expert_interests"] = [
  {"title": title}
  for title
  in json.loads(data["expert_interests"].replace("'", '"'))
  # only use this line (instead of above) if you trust the source of this data
  # in eval(data["expert_interests"])
]

print(data)
# {'expert_interests': [{'title': 'Machine learning'}, {'title': 'deep learning'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the value to a list of strings and use a list comprehension to create a list of dicts from it.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
d = {'expert_interests': "['Machine learning', 'deep learning']"}
d['expert_interests'] = [{"title" : t} for t in literal_eval(d['expert_interests'])]
print(d) 
# {'expert_interests': [{'title': 'Machine learning'}, {'title': 'deep learning'}]}
```